# Antiaromaticity can be explained by Hückel method?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, aromaticity

Pentalene is one of the most famous antiaromatic molecules. But I obtained its energy of $\pi$ system as $8\alpha+10.46\beta$ by Hückel method (with a bit complicated but straightforward calculation). This value is lower than that of localized form $8(\alpha+\beta)$. So Hückel method looks to be not able to explain antiaromaticity. Are there any misunderstandings? It seems that many of antiaromatic molecules are predicted lower than their all-ethylene counterparts.

(I don't think radicality is a key for antiaromaticity, and I'd like to know a general, quantum mechanical explanation about antiaromatic molecules if it exists.)

Comment: Aromatic or antiaromatic, it is still conjugated, so no wonder it is better off than the all-ethylene analog. The general explanation is precisely where you don't think it is.

Comment: With Huckel MOT, aromaticity / antiaromaticity should be determined with reference to a linear conjugated analogue, so e.g. cyclobutadiene is compared with butadiene, not two ethylenes. I am not sure how this carries over to pentalene. Arguably, Huckel's rules were designed for monocyclic systems, not polycyclic ones.

Comment: I solved the secular equation of pentalene, whose matrix has two resonance integral in addition to that of cyclooctatetraene. The solutions have no degeneracy, so I think penetalene is not expected to be radical.

Comment: @sakai right.  Pentalene is not a radical.  But it will have a low-lying acceptor orbital and thus is highly reactive an an electrophile.  Which, of course, is what actually happens.  Fill the low-lying acceptor orbital and the resulting dimension is quite stable.